# Responsive using bootstrap change from two columns to one column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use **bootstrap v.4** for responsive design with two column, and use two md and xs breakpoints. below is my code also [**jsfiddle link**](https://jsfiddle.net/h30jjvgo/6/)

```
.left-box{
    background-color:red;
    height:50px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
 }
.right-box{
    background-color:yellow;
    height:150px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
 }

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 left-box pull-xs-left">A1</div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 right-box pull-xs-right">B1</div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 left-box pull-xs-left">A2</div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 right-box pull-xs-right">B2</div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 left-box pull-xs-left">A3</div>
</div>
```

In xs breakpoint result is OK as following picture:

[image]

I want in md breakpoint result as follow

expected md breakpoint

[image]

but result is:

[image]

Is any way to solve this with css?

Comment: Your code and fiddle don't work to acheive "in xs breakpoint result is OK as following picture:" The `col-xs-3`, `col-xs-9` don't stack vertically. Also there is no `pull-xs-left`, `pull-xs-right` in Bootstrap 3.x. Are you adding custom CSS for these?

Comment: excuse me, I use Bootstrap v.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `col-md-*` instead and a little CSS to enable `float:right` on the md grid tier.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 left-box">A1</div>
        <div class="col-md-9 right-box pull-md-right">B1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 left-box">A2</div>
        <div class="col-md-9 right-box pull-md-right">B2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 left-box">A3</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width:992px) {
    .pull-md-right {
        float:right;
    }
}
```

<kbd>[**Codeply Demo**](http://www.codeply.com/go/yRsQ4bhqm8)</kbd>

*EDIT*
Bootstrap 4 already has `pull-md-right` so you don't need the extra CSS and it works fine. You shouldn't use `pull-xs-right`.

http://www.codeply.com/go/cED1AH8AX9

Comment: your answer not work when i change left-box height, In fact accidentally your answer been true

Comment: Yes, it does work based on your ORIGINAL question which has now changed

Comment: I change question for general case, do you any way for?

Answer (score 0):

Why you can't use two columns like the following fiddle?

https://jsfiddle.net/h30jjvgo/2/

Left and right divs can be inside seperate divs.

```
 .left-box{
 background-color:red;
  height:100px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  float:none;
  width:100%;
}
.right-box{
 background-color:yellow;
  height:150px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  width:100%;
}

 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="col-xs-3 left-box pull-xs-left">A1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 left-box pull-xs-left">A2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 left-box pull-xs-left">A3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="col-xs-9 right-box pull-xs-right">B1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-9 right-box pull-xs-right">B2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't achieve the xs alignment in your solution.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use col-xs classes for the left and right divs.

Comment: plz look at to xs breakpoint in Question (first picture), your answer not work in xs breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

Try following approach, with 3, 9 columns with all the inner section 12 columns

https://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmanzoor/h30jjvgo/5/

```
.left-box {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  float: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.right-box {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 100%;
}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3 left-box pull-xs-left">A1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 left-box pull-xs-left">A2</div>
      <div class="col-xs-3 left-box pull-xs-left">A3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-9 right-box pull-xs-right">B1</div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 right-box pull-xs-right">B2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: plz look at to xs breakpoint in Question (first picture), your answer not work in xs breakpoint